# Why does my program keeps repeating the line even if a valid input is enter?

Tags: objective-c, dice

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    int userInput= 6 ;
    char userChar='\0';

    //creating new instances
    Dice *a = [[Dice alloc] init];
    //creating new objects
    Die *d1 = [[Die alloc] initWithSides:&userInput];
    Die *d2 = [[Die alloc] initWithSides:&userInput];
    //adding dices
    [a addDice:d1];
    [a addDice:d2];

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Press R to roll dices and Q to exit \n> ");
        scanf("%c",&userChar);

        if (userChar == 'r' | userChar =='R')
        {

            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                [a rollDice];
                printf("Dice 1 =%d\n",d1.returns);
                printf("Dice 2 =%d\n",d2.returns);
                printf("The total values of both dice is %d\n",a.totalValue);
                printf("Does the dices have same value? Y(1) N(0) => %d\n\n",a.allSame);
            }
        }
        else if (userChar == 'q' | userChar == 'Q')
        {
            return 0;
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Enter a valid command!\n");
        }

    }

}
}
```

I tried to create a loop that repeats itself and when r is pressed, do the roll dice and q when user wants to quit the program. otherwise, keep repeating itself until either proper input is enter. but i don't get it why if i enter an input, it will repeat the phase that are in else? Like this,

```
Press R to roll dices and Q to exit 
>l
Enter a valid command!
Press R to roll dices and Q to exit 
>Enter a valid command!  //Why does it repeats itself here??
Press R to roll dices and Q to exit 
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey try to use following code it must work.

```
scanf(" %c",&userChar);
```

Comment: Works like a button! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now I its your task to find out the reason behind this change

Answer (score 0):

If you enter

```
 l<RETURN>
```

in your console then there are two characters in the input buffer: the "l" and
a newline.
The first `scanf()` reads the "l" and the second `scanf()` reads the newline.

While this can be solved by modifying the scan format, a much better solution to read
an entire line from user input is to use `fgets()`, e.g.

```
char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
    userChar = buf[0];
    // ...
}
```

And note that the logical "or" operator is `||`, not `|`!